# Python Encryption using Keyphrase

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, python-2.x, vigenere

I am trying to make a python program that will take in plain text and encrypt it using a key. It is written with python 2.7.4

This is my code so far

```
def encrypter(intext, shift, modder):
    plain = list(intext)
    out = ''
    j = 0
    key = list(shift)
    for i in plain:
        if mod > 0:
            x = chr((ord(i) + ord(key[(j % (len(plain) - 1)) % len(key)]) - 48) % 58 + 48)
        if mod < 0:
            x = chr(((ord(i) - ord(key[(j % (len(plain) - 1)) % len(key)]) - 48) % 58 + 48))
        out += x
        j += 1
    return out
sel = raw_input("Encrypt (e)/ Decrypt (d)")
if sel == 'e':
    mod = 1
elif sel == 'd':
    mod = -1
else:
    mod = 0
    print('Enter a proper value!')
if mod != 0:
    print(encrypter(raw_input('Enter the text:'), raw_input('Enter the key-phrase:'), mod)
```

When I encrypt something I get this:

```
C:\Users\aesha_000\py\Scripts\python.exe "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Resources/functiontest3.py"
Encrypt (e)/ Decrypt (d)e
Enter the text:alex
Enter the key-phrase:pass
]Yd:

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But the problem is when I then Decrypt it again I get the wrong output:

```
C:\Users\aesha_000\py\Scripts\python.exe "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Resources/functiontest3.py"
Encrypt (e)/ Decrypt (d)d
Enter the text:]Yd:
Enter the key-phrase:pass
a2e>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does anyone know the answer to this or am I just being stupid?

Comment: Just put +48 in mod<0 section...just guessing..without Implementing considering symmetry

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python File Encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105064/python-file-encryption)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `% 58 + 48`.
I'm assuming you're using it for having printable ascii chars, but you should not. You're loosing information.

If you want to display "not printable ascii chard", use base64.

Comment: If I use that I get

 `C:\Users\aesha_000\py\Scripts\python.exe "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Resources/functiontest3.py"
Encrypt (e)/ Decrypt (d)e
Enter the text:alex
Enter the key-phrase:test
����

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: Use base64 on encrypted text, and debase64 if you need to decypher

Comment: That's a classical cipher. It doesn't really improve the security of it when using the complete byte space, but it helps finding bugs, when using only printable chars.

Comment: I am not allowed to use any other cipher, as this is coursework for an exam!