# Python File Encryption

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, encryption

I need to encrypt a file with a key phrase for part of an assessment. I am doing mine in python and have run into a problem. It is written using python 2.7.4

My code is as follows:

import array

```
def encrypter(intext, shift, modder):
    plain2 = list(intext)
    plain = array.fromlist(plain2)
    out = ''
    j = 0
    key = list(shift)
    for c in plain:
        if mod > 0:
            x = chr((ord(c) + ord(key[(j % (len(plain) - 1)) % len(key)]) - 48) % 58 + 48)
        if mod < 0:
            x = chr((ord(c) - ord(key[(j % (len(plain) - 1)) % len(key)]) - 48) % 58 + 48)
        out += x
        j += 1
    return out
sel = raw_input("Encrypt (e)/ Decrypt (d)")
if sel == 'e':
    mod = 1
    intext = open(raw_input("what is your file"),'r')
    shift = raw_input("what is your first password")
    encrypter(intext, shift, mod)

else:
    pass
```

My problem is that whenever I run this with a file called text1.txt I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Tasks/task3.py", line 22, in <module>
    encrypter(intext, shift, mod)
  File "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Tasks/task3.py", line 5, in encrypter
    plain = array.fromlist(plain2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromlist'
```

Can anyone suggest a change in my code? I need this relatively quickly as my assessment is in an hour or so!

Comment: If this work is important you needed to start it sooner, before it became urgent. It's urgent for you now, not for us.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you need the `array` module at all. Won't something like this work?

```
def encrypter(intext, shift, modder):
    plain = intext
    out = ''
    j = 0
    key = shift
    for c in plain:
        if mod > 0:
            x = chr((ord(c) + ord(key[(j % (len(plain) - 1)) % len(key)]) - 48) % 58 + 48)
        if mod < 0:
            x = chr((ord(c) - ord(key[(j % (len(plain) - 1)) % len(key)]) - 48) % 58 + 48)
        out += x
        j += 1
    return out
```

Comment: #Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Tasks/task3.py", line 22, in <module>
    encrypter(intext, shift, mod)
  File "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Tasks/task3.py", line 5, in encrypter
    plain = array.array.fromlist(plain2)
TypeError: descriptor 'fromlist' requires a 'array.array' object but received a 'list'

Comment: You probably don't even need the `array` module. See my edit.

Comment: when I do that I get this error          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Tasks/task3.py", line 22, in <module>
    encrypter(intext, shift, mod)
  File "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Tasks/task3.py", line 10, in encrypter
    x = chr((ord(c) + ord(key[(j % (len(plain) - 1)) % len(key)]) - 48) % 58 + 48)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 15 found

Comment: Write `intext = open(raw_input("what is your file"),'r').read()`.

Answer (score 1):

import array class from module

```
from array import array
plain = array('b', plain2)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Tasks/task3.py", line 22, in <module>
    encrypter(intext, shift, mod)
  File "D:/Programming/Computing GCSE/Tasks/task3.py", line 5, in encrypter
    plain = array.fromlist(plain2)
TypeError: descriptor 'fromlist' requires a 'array.array' object but received a 'list'